# clang makes recompile everithing at each build in cmake

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Here is a small c++ code, adapted from the tutorial [*Step 1*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/A%20Basic%20Starting%20Point.html) of CMake :

```cpp
// tutorial.cxx
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(Tutorial)

# add the executable
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
```

I used the extension of vscode *CmakeTools*, and I noticed that every time I build the project, it recompiles everything, even if nothing was changed. After some investigations, I found that the configuration of the project is made by vscode using this command :

```sh
/usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/clang-10 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/clang++-10 -H/home/user/Bureau/projet/step1 -B/home/user/Bureau/projet/step1/build -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

(and if I configure by hand in the terminal with this command, it has the same behavior).

I noticed that if I configure the build directory without the option `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/bin/clang++-10`, there is no problem afterwards: if a `make` if nothing has been charged in source, it doesn't recompile.

I have actually 2 questions :

1. Why does the option `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH` induces such a behavior?
2. How to configure vscode so it doesn't use this option anymore?

**EDIT :**

I tried to configure the project with another compiler (in the list, vscode proposes `Clang10`, `GCC 8.4.0` and `GCC 9.3.0`). With `Clang` all is recompiled at each time, but this is not the case if I take `GCC`.

This answers my second question: use another compiler.
But still, I wonder why does Clang recompile everything ?

Comment: only run `cmake` when you have changed the number of C++ files, otherwise run `make` from the build directory, how does cmake know which compiler to use if you don't tell it

Comment: yes it took a default compiler (gcc insted of clang), see the edited message above

Comment: look at the make files build, it is Make that decides to recompile based on the rules

Comment: Your post is very helpful to me. When I find /bin/clang-10 is a symbol link, I try replace /bin/clang-10 with which it points(/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang), every thing works fine like gcc. Try 
`/usr/local/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang++ -H/home/user/Bureau/projet/step1 -B/home/user/Bureau/projet/step1/build -G "Unix Makefiles"`. And in vscode,I update the path in user-local Cmake kits to avoid manually run cmake command.

Comment: so what clang are you using? (installed from where/how?) Actual clang? or the **Apple** clang that comes with the Xcode developer tools? what do you see from running `clang --version`? and what's the output of your `cmake --version`?

Comment: how exactly are you invoking build? what action are you taking / button are you pressing / command are you running? And show the exact output. How are you certain that everything is being recompiled instead of just _looking like_ things are being recompiled?

Comment: are you using [CMake Tools kits](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/kits.html) or are you using [CMake Presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html)? I'll assume kits since you haven't mentioned anything. What if you switch to using presets?